# Statistics probability density function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value

I was given the probability density function

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 0.75(1 - x^2) & \text{if} -1 < x < 1 \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases},$$

and I want to calculate the mean. I know that the definition of mean for a continuous random variable is the integral from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ of $xf(x) dx$.

My question was, since my function does not go to infinity, it only goes from -1 to 1 and is 0 elsewhere, how do I calculate that integral for the mean? Is it zero?

Comment: The integral is over the [support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(mathematics)) of the distribution, not necessarily from $-\infty$ to $\infty$. Also, as a hint for the solution, notice that your density is symmetric around the $y$-axis.

Comment: The mean is computed via  $\int_{-1}^{1}  x \, f(x) \, dx,$  since $\int_{-\infty}^{-1}$ and $\int_1^\infty$ are both zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your density is even, symmetric around zero and unimodal thus Mean, Mode and Median are all zero. No further calculation are needed

Comment: wouldn't that mean that the Mean is the integral from -1 to 1 of x*f(x)? so not zero as some have suggested?

Comment: @FrodoBaggins : obviously $\int_{-1}^{1}xf(x)dx=0$ for the reasons I wrote. Anyway you can calculate the integral which is an immediate one

Answer (score 2):

As others have already said:

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} xf(x)dx$

$= \int_{-\infty}^{-1} xf(x)dx + \int_{-1}^{1}xf(x)dx + \int_{1}^{\infty}xf(x)dx$

$= 0 + \int_{-1}^{1}xf(x)dx + 0$

$= \int_{-1}^{1}xf(x)dx$

Comment: would that apply for Median as well as Mean? So it would be from -1 to M instead of from -inf to M?